# How to check presence of optional attribute inside a composite component

Tags: jsf-2, attributes, composite-component

I need to verify whether an optional attribute has been passed or not within my composite component. How can I achieve this?

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="attr1" />
    <composite:attribute name="attr2" required="false" /> <!-- means OPTIONAL -->
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <!-- How I can verify here whether attr2 is present or not whenever this component is used? -->
</composite:implementation>
```

Setting the `default` attribute to `xxx` for `<composite:attribute>` is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could just check if `#{not empty cc.attrs.attr2}` evaluates to `true`.

E.g. inside the `rendered` attribute of an arbitrary component:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty cc.attrs.attr2}">
        Attribute attr2 is not empty!
    </h:panelGroup>
</composite:implementation>
```

Comment: by the way it is checking the value of `attr2` is empty or not and rendering accordingly.

Comment: It is not working as I expected. It is checking the VALUE of `attr2` is empty (null) or not and rendering accordingly. But I want to add a check (with in my CC implementation) if `attr2` itself is PRESENT or not. Say my check on `<cc:myComponent attr1="" attr2="">` should give me `true` as `attr2` itself is passed. AND `<cc:myComponent attr1="">` should give me `false` as `attr2` itself is not passed. Please suggest.

Comment: You could compare to `null`. `rendered="#{cc.attrs.attr2 != null}"`.

Comment: What's the functional requirement for this strange approach?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. There is no functional requirement but I want my CC component simple to look.

Answer (score 4):

You can check to see if the expression exists using the method:

> cc.getValueExpression('someAttribute')

```
<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputText rendered="#{cc.getValueExpression('attr2') ne null}">
        Attribute attr2 has been passed!
    </h:outputText>
</composite:implementation>
```

Comment: If i were him, i would choose this one as accepted answer.

Comment: This is more helpful than the accepted answer, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11368475/7769052

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally add attributes to component via:

```
<c:if><f:attribute>
```

Sample:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="label" />
    <composite:attribute name="required" default="false" />
    <composite:attribute name="readonly" default="false" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
    <composite:attribute name="title" />
    <composite:attribute name="placeholder" />
    <composite:attribute name="maxlength" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <p:inputText
      id="field"
      value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <c:if test="#{empty cc.attrs.maxLength}">
           <f:attribute name="maxlength" value="#{cc.attrs.maxlength}" />
        </c:if>
    </p:inputText>
</composite:implementation>
```

I Found the answer in:

[How not to set an attribute of a component inside a composite component if it is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474926/how-not-to-set-an-attribute-of-a-component-inside-a-composite-component-if-it-is)

Comment: This will result in a null pointer exception, you have to check for *not empty*: `  <c:if test="#{not empty cc.attrs.maxLength}">`